# How to fix 'table or view does not not exist' error

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, stored-functions

Package name 'emp_helper' was created under 'emp' user.

1. A new user 'emp_client' has been created and granted with execute
   and    debug privielge for the 'emp_helper' package.
2. It has function and its code is given below

When I ran the procedure with input(111 and FULL), im getting below

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "EMP.EMP_HELPER", line 18
ORA-06512: at line 10

**Note:** Line 10: v_lst_no   NUMBER;
Line 18: SELECT

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY emp.emp_helper AS

    FUNCTION get_version_no (
        p_countryid          IN VARCHAR2,
        p_emp_type           IN VARCHAR2,
        p_processed_version  OUT NUMBER
    ) RETURN NUMBER
    AS
        v_latest_no        NUMBER;
        v_lst_no           NUMBER;
        v_job_in_progress  VARCHAR2(1);
        v_result           NUMBER;
        v_cust_cnt         NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        BEGIN
            SELECT MIN(version_no) INTO v_lst_no
            FROM   emp_identification
            WHERE  country_id = p_countryid;                 
        END;

        p_processed_version := v_lst_no;
        RETURN v_latest_no;
    END;

END emp_helper;
```

I expect a number to be returned when executed.

Comment: What happens when you run call the function as `emp`? Is the package declared with definer or invoker rights - i.e. does it specify `authid`, and if so as what?

Comment: When I call the function as emp, function returns the expected value and it has been declared with authid as current_user Under EMP user

Comment: Right, as you've used `current_user` then the *caller* has to have privileges on the table, granted directly to them. Is that really what you want though - do you have a reason for needing invoker rights?

Comment: I have given the SELECT grant to the user(emp_client) but still issue persists

Comment: After removing authid as current_user from the declaration, it worked.

Comment: By the way, putting `begin ... end` around a statement doesn't do anything.

Comment: @William ,I have cut short 1000 line of codes to fewer lines. Original code has got used Begin and End statments for some other purposed

Comment: Thanks Alex and William :)

Answer (score 0):

Use EMP.emp_identification instead of emp_identification and GRANT SELECT ON EMP.emp_identification TO emp_user. Or, you could create  SINONYM for EMP.emp_identification (public or just in schema of emp_user).

Comment: It helped after creating the synonym by reducing errors to fewer but still need to comment the - 'authid current_user' statement. Now the proc successfully executed for the emp_client user.

Comment: Thanks Virgil lonescu